# php the foreach loop applied to DomNodeList skips an element when appending

Tags: php, foreach, domdocument, appendchild

I am loading elements from a page with php. It works almost. The only thing is that from all the anchor elements I try to load it only gives me half. It skips every second element. Here is some of my php script

```
$div = @$doc->getElementById('topicList');

$anchs=$div->getElementsByTagName('a');
//echo $anchs->length;  it does have the correct length

$container = $doc->createElement("div");
$container->setAttribute('class', 'relative');


foreach ($anchs as $anch){

$container->appendChild($anch);
}   
       /// /////////
$expDiv = $doc->createElement("div");
$expDiv->setAttribute('class', 'explanation_div');
$container->appendChild($expDiv);
echo utf8_decode(@$doc->saveXML($container));
```

So this only puts out every second anchor element, not all of them.

I have tried it with the for loop, but that's not allowed on a DomNodeList.

I think it must have something to do with  appendChild, and that it might append the next one over the previous or something, but I don't see how.

Has someone had this problem before, or can you see what I am doing wrong? 
Help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it now. It turns out the `appendChild` method pops the item of the list, so all the elements move back a position. This worked:

```
for ( $i=0;$i<$anchs->length;){   // so don't increase $i
    $anch=$anchs->item($i);

    $container->appendChild($anch);
}
```